# Xpath returns empty list

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Somehow this doesn't seem to work, the title string is always returned empty

```
import requests
from lxml import html

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
url ='http://www.hayneedle.com/product/discoverngrowjumperoo.cfm'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
title = tree.xpath('//h1[@class="h2 inline"]//text()')
print(title)
```

[image]
Any help would be appreiated, thank you !

Comment: It works for me. `['Discover-n-Grow Jumperoo']` is returned. I am using Python 2.7 on macOS.

Comment: I am using python 3.6 on windows, and it returns this [ ], I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong

Comment: Seems like the site doesn't like to be scraped. the html returned contains of captcha.

Comment: Tried using python2.7, still empty. How come it works for you ?

Comment: python3.5 works

Comment: @Dawzer site has captcha to prevent web scraping.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I should do ?

Comment: @Dawzer Try using web driver using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). As you are actually using a browser, most of the sites won't be able to tell that you are scraping.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a vpn and it actually worked, seems like the website was blocking my original ip address.